# Why is my function returning undefined, when it should return a number?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to solve challenge on one website, and my code behaves strange... It returns undefined... What is interesting: if I print value of "sum" just before return statement, it is correct value in the console... Any help would be awesome

```
function digital_root(n) {
  let text = String(n);
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    sum += Number(text[i]);
  }
  if (String(sum).length > 1) {
    digital_root(sum);
  } else {
    return sum;
  }
}

let score = digital_root(456);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to propagate the recursive return value upwards. If you call `digital_root()` without `return`ing the child's result then the parent call returns `undefined`.

```
if (String(sum).length > 1) {
  return digital_root(sum);
}
```